# Entity Framework - querying a many-to-many relationship table

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I have a many-to-many relationship defined like so:

```
Employees
--------------
EmployeeID (PK)

Roles
--------------
RoleID (PK)

EmployeeRoles
--------------
EmployeeID (PK, FK)
RoleID (PK, FK)
```

I'm trying to get a list of Employees, given a list or RoleIDs:

```
private MyDBEntities _entities;

public SqlEmployeesRepository(MyDBEntities entities)
{            
    _entities = entities;
}

public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployeesForRoles(int[] roleIds)
{
    // get employees
}
```

But if I try and do `_entities.EmployeeRoles`, there is no EmployeeRoles object. My edmx looks like this:

[image]

So it's recognizing the relationship between the two tables, but it's not creating an entity object for EmployeeRoles.

How can I get a distinct list of Employees given a list of role id's?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The relationship between the tables Role and Employee is represented as a navigation property - each `Employees` property in the `Role` entity will only contain the Employees that have this particular role.

Putting it the other way round - every Employee's `Roles` property only contains the roles that particular employee has.

Given a set of roles `roleIds` to look for you can use this to get the list of employees that have a role within that set:

```
public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployeesForRoles(int[] roleIds)
{
    var employees = _entities.Employees
                             .Where( x=> x.Roles.Any(r => roleIds.Contains(r.RoleID)))
   return employees;
}
```

**Edit:**

The other way to get the employees is to attack the problem from the other side of the relationship (starting with the role, not the employee). This is most likely not as efficient as the first approach, since we have to de-duplicate employees (otherwise employees with i.e. two roles would show up twice):

```
public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployeesForRoles(int[] roleIds)
{
    var employees = _entities.Roles
                             .Where( r => roleIds.Contains(r.RoleID))
                             .SelectMany( x=> x.Employees)
                             .Distinct()
   return employees;
}
```

Comment: Lol, I was just going to post this as an alternative to your first solution (with `Distinct` etc.), but now it's no alternative anymore. Can you leave your first solution as another option in your answer. It was an interesting way, or was something wrong with it?

Comment: @Slauma: Yes it is an alternative - but this seemed more straight-forward after looking at the problem for so I scratched the first approach - let me dig it up again ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe?

```
var results = from r in db.Roles
              where roleIds.Contains(r.Id)
              select r.Employees;
```